# MySQL unique index replacing one foreign key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I have a pivot table named `pivot` that maps `tableA` to tableB`.

`pivot` has the following fields: `tA_id`, `tB_id`.

I have two foreign keys - one on each field.

1) `pivot_tA_id_foreign` for `tA_id` references `id` on `tableA`

2) `pivot_tB_id_foreign` for `tB_id` references `id` on `tableB`

Now when I go to add one UNIQUE index on both the columns like so:

`ALTER TABLE 'pivot' ADD UNIQUE 'pivot_tA_id_tB_id_unique' ('tA_id', 'tB_id')`

the `pivot_tA_id_foreign` index disappears.

I need both the foreign indexes AND the UNIQUE on the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your can either use an alter table command (you do not need the quotes, which you have incorrectly typed) or include the the unique constraint within the pivot table definition:

```
ALTER TABLE pivot ADD UNIQUE pivot_tA_id_tB_id_unique (tA_id, tB_id);

OR

create table pivot(
      tA_id int, 
      tB_id int,
      foreign key(tA_id) references tableA(id),
      foreign key(tB_id) references tableB(id),
      constraint pivot_tA_id_tB_id_unique UNIQUE (tA_id, tB_id)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try executing the SQL statement without the single quotes...

```
ALTER TABLE pivot ADD UNIQUE pivot_tA_id_tB_id_unique (tA_id, tB_id)
```